# How do I replace #(lf) and change to linebreak?

Tags: sql-server

I have a piece of MSSQL that is super long with #(lf) instead of line break. Is there a short cut to find and replace all the #(lf) in the code with a line break? What should I replace it with? '/n' is not working

```
set transaction isolation level Read Uncommitted#(lf)SET NOCOUNT ON#(lf)DECLARE @FAC OID,#(lf)@area OID,#(lf)........
```

Comment: try `\n`. backslash is the escape character (pretty sure)

Comment: CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)

Comment: Do you mean in an SSMS text editor?

Comment: Surly this is a simple find-and-replace, either in SSMS or some other tool eg Notepad++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are the default shortcuts to perform the find/replace in a query window using the current versions of SSMS and ADS.

SSMS:

- Press CTRL+H (for find/replace)
- Press ALT+E (for use regular expressions)
- Specify the regex to find the string: #\((lf\)
- Specify the target value (\r\n Windows line terminator or \n for Linux): \r\n
- Press ALT+A (to find/replace all)

ADS:

- Press CTRL+H (for find/replace)
- Press ALT+R (for use regular expressions)
- Specify the regex to find the string: #\((lf\)
- Specify the target value (\r\n Windows line terminator or \n for Linux): \r\n
- Press CTL+ALT+Enter (to find/replace all)